# Convert flat roundish meshes to angular meshes

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves

I extracted road markings using Open Data and Python. In the attached screenshot the road markings are still rounded. Since road marking is usually not roundish but angular, I would like to design the meshes also angular.

The attached screenshot is a. svg image imported into Blender. Would it be possible to convert all surfaces into splines and then widen them to create rectangular road markings?

Is there a solution in Blender?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

this is one possible way to make roundish curves  into angular meshes:

this is a curve object (closed):

[image]

in edit mode you can select all nodes and convert them as vector

[image]

which will "straighten" curves changing nodes handles

[image]

which will become

[image]

if you can get those shapes as svg, you could try steps above...

edit:

note, you *can* get perfectly square shapes if source svg curves have suitable control points, like in this example below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution! That doesn't look bad, but road markings are rather rectangular and less trapezoidal. The screenshot above is an .svg image imported into Blender. Would it be possible to convert all surfaces into splines and widen them afterwards?

Comment: @freddykrueger afaik, svg imported in blender should result in a curve (based on splines) object... you _can_ convert that to mesh, later (alt-c in object mode)

Comment: Is there a way, that the meshes look like this (https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/01/16/26/45/240_F_116264554_1SmZ4pehMmMjg5bMFCwyD6OmYBcN7Xbz.jpg)?

Comment: @freddykrueger depending on the source svg, yes: see updated answer